# Non-recursive Merge Sort using Stacks

Tags: java, stack, mergesort

I'm currently working on an assignment where I am supposed to write mergeSort using stacks! I have a pretty good idea on how stacks and mergesort works, however I am not sure how to finish my code with stacks. I've set up a base case, and here I'm trying to use an in-place method where I just theoretically divide up my array without creating a new one by changing the markers. I am pretty new to this and unsure of how I should proceed.. 
I think this is the sort of thing I'm going for :

Base Case --> PC = 1

```
if (callStack.peek().PC == 1) {
            if (callStack.peek().start == callStack.peek().stop) {   //length <=1 
                callStack.pop(); //either done, or array length was 1
                merge(A, callStack.peek().start, callStack.peek().mid, callStack.peek().stop);

                if (callStack.empty()){
                    break;
                }
                callStack.peek().PC++;
            } else {
                callStack.peek().PC++;
            }
            continue;
        }`
```

any left divided array --> PC = 2
any right divided array --> PC == 3

```
int mid = (callStack.peek().stop-callStack.peek().start)/2;

        if (callStack.peek().PC == 2) {
            if (callStack.peek().start != callStack.peek().stop) {
            current = new ProgramFrame(callStack.peek().start, callStack.peek().mid, 1);
            callStack.push(current);
            continue;
            }
        }

        if (callStack.peek().PC == 3) {
            if (callStack.peek().start != callStack.peek().stop) {
            current = new ProgramFrame(callStack.peek().mid+1, callStack.peek().stop, 1);
            callStack.push(current);
            continue;
            }
        }
```

the merged of both --> PC ==4

if (callStack.peek().PC == 4) {
                merge(A, callStack.peek().start, callStack.peek().mid, callStack.peek().stop);

```
            callStack.pop();

            if (!callStack.empty()) {
                if (callStack.peek().PC == 2) callStack.peek().start callStack.peek().mid; //help??
                if (callStack.peek().PC == 3) callStack.peek().mid+1, callStack.peek().stop; //help??
                callStack.peek().PC++;
                continue;
```

I'm sorry this is such a long post :( I am just really unsure of how to fix it and how to continue it...

** also merge and my programeFrame look okay, but if you need to see them I can send them too!

Comment: I have 4 questions: **1.** What is the first element of the stack? (I guess `new ProgramFrame(0, A.length, 1)`) **2.** What are the parameters of the `ProgramFrame`-constructor? (I guess start index, end index and initial PC) **3.** What is the `PC` of `ProgramFrame`? **4.** What are the parameters of `merge`?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't 'fix' it, you need to design it first... One of (multiple!) issues is: where do you set the stack top item's `mid` member, which you try to use for `merge()` and for `new ProgramFrame`? Another one: is your `int mid` actually the 'mid' position or rather an (approximate) length of a sub-array?

Comment: Formatting tips: make sure each source line begins with 4 spaces; add 2 spaces at the end of the line which begins with 'any left divided array'.

Comment: Are you sure you need the two lines starting with `if (callStack.peek().PC == something)` under the `PC==4` branch?